# python ssh/rsync hang when run as windows service

Tags: python, windows, service, ssh, rsync

I have a script that's supposed to pull files from a Linux box to my Windows box using rsync. I designed it as a Windows service, and that bit seems to work fine. The rsync and ssh executables launch, connect to the Linux machine, authenticate using keys, but dont copy any of the files.
Here's the core of the script, excluding most of the Windows service stuff.

```
import subprocess
RSYNCPULL = '''"C:\\Program Files\\cwRsync\\bin\\rsync.exe" --remove-source-files
           --no-motd -e "\'C:\\Program Files\\cwRsync\\bin\\ssh.exe\'"
           user@IP:/var/log/* /cygdrive/c/logs/'''

class LogCopy( win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework ):
   #various functions for starting/stopping the service
    def sleep( self, sec ):
        win32api.Sleep( sec*1000, True )
    def start( self ):
        self.runflag = True
        while self.runflag:
            subprocess.call( RSYNCPULL )
            self.sleep( 10 )  

if __name__ == "__main__":
    qin32serviceutil.HandleCommandLine( LogCopy )
```

Answer (score 0):

The "*" char might pe interpreted by the Windows shell and expanded.
Try to either:

- put a backslash before your "*". That way rsync is going to expand it for you on the other side of the connection
- remove the "*" and then use the -r option of rsync to do a recursive copy of the directory

Answer (score 0):

Found out what it was. I was running the task as system. I had setup ssh keys under the administrator account but not system. So ssh was hanging at the prompt to save the key.